# Best setup for glossy reflective look

Tags: shaders

What is the best way to set up my layout / scene to get maximum reflection & gloss on my object. I want a liquid black latex look, looks great with the nodes I have used in Shading but of course when I go to layout just looks only a little bit shiny.

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots, maybe share your file?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a problem here. Layout defaults to Solid view, where every material is shown with only a basic color (defaulting to grey). Shading defaults to Material Preview, which is basically EEVEE rendered but with no shadows and an environment HDRI to make reflective things look good. What you will see when you actually render the scene to file should match the Render view. Note that you can change between these different views in the top right corner of the 3D Viewport editor. By default, the actual environment lighting (AKA the Blender “World”) in use is solid grey, and thus if you’re using EEVEE or even Cycles but there’s nothing else to reflect, glossy things will look wrong. You’ll want to set up some kind of environment lighting. You can do this in Shading by changing the Shader Nodes editor from Object to World in the pull down list in the top left of its header.

Here’s some pages in the Blender manual on the subjects:

1. [Viewport Shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html)
2. [Lighting -> World Environment](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/world.html)

Comment: ah OK thank you, I will check out the shader nodes !